# AvPlayer stop playing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to play a video that i am downloading from the net with `AVPlayer` :

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1"]];

    audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName]];
    avPlayerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:audioPlayer];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    [audioPlayer play];

    [[self.view layer] addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
```

and i done it after 50% from the file is downloaded. it's start playing and in the 50% of the playing process it playing nothing.

I want to know if there is a way to append a file that already playing in `AVPlayer` .

Comment: u want stop audio when u press the button? bcz i didn't understand ur question....

Answer (score 0):

```
[player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(0, 1)];
[player pause];
```

Comment: Add more information to your answer. Like what you do and why.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question.